# grep lines without a mentioned pattern

Tags: awk, grep, file-handling

I have a table

```
"OG0000000" character(0)
"OG0000001" c("vvin|GSVIVT01000436001", "vvin|GSVIVT01011363001", "vvin|GSVIVT01013966001", "vvin|GSVIVT01017482001")
```

I only want to grep the lines which do not have character(0) in the second column

Comment: See GNU grep's man page: `man grep | less +/invert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whenever you're talking about fields it's a job for awk, not grep:

```
awk '$2 != "character(0)"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -v                                                                    .

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep -v "character(0)" yourtable`.

This assumes that `character(0)` doesn't occur anywhere else in the lines that you *do* want.